# How to fix bootstrap distance between an HTML input text and a button (on quantity control functionality)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to make a quantity control functionality for my website. As you can see in the Code Snippet below, I want to have my text input of this control at 38px wide. Everything works fine when my table's cell is lower than 38px wide. But when I put something bigger (like a title) my quantity control brakes into parts!

So, my question is: How to zero the distance between the bootstrap input text and the button?

I want to achieve this, regardless of the length of the cell:

[image]

```css
.quantity-style {
  text-align: center;  
  min-width: 38px; 
  max-width: 38px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<table border="1" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 50px;">

<tr>
  <td style="padding: 10px;">
        Hello - This is a test with big title
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td style="padding: 10px;">

        <div class="input-group">

          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number btn-sm" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[2]">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
         
          <input type="text" name="quant[2]" class="form-control input-number input-sm quantity-style" value="0" min="0" max="15">
      
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number btn-sm" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[2]">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
          </span>

        </div>
   
  </td>
</tr>
 
</table>
```

Comment: In the snippet I get  exactly the same thing as your image in chrome. What are you viewing it in?

Comment: Never mind. I just saw it in Explorer 10 and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new class `quantity-wrapper` to the parent of all 3 elements `[ - | 0 | + ]`

Then set the style to the desired width of `38px`

Check it out:

```css
.quantity-style{
  text-align: center;  
  min-width: 38px; 
  max-width: 38px;
}

.quantity-wrapper{
  width: 38px; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<table border="1" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 50px;">

<tr>
  <td style="padding: 10px;">
        Hello - This is a test with big title
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td style="padding: 10px;">

        <div class="input-group quantity-wrapper">

          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number btn-sm" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[2]">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
         
          <input type="text" name="quant[2]" class="form-control input-number input-sm quantity-style" value="0" min="0" max="15">
      
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number btn-sm" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[2]">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
          </span>

        </div>
   
  </td>
</tr>
 
</table>
```